# EasyOCR Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, machine-learning, ocr

I got this issue

```
pip install easyocr
```

on python env

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

result = reader.readtext('./reports/dilate/NP6221833_126.png', workers=1)
```

finally

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved downgrading to the nov 2021 version of opencv

```
pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.60
```

Comment: update: merged in the last version

Comment: Thx man you saved my life, I've been struggling with it for days.