# EasyOCR segfault when used with Decord

Tags: python, easyocr

- EasyOCR version: 1.7.1
- Decord version: 0.6.0
- Python version: 3.11.7

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import decord
import easyocr

ocr = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
```

`[1]    1106258 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287219/python-easyocr-crashing-python-vm-doesnt-weem-to-be-related-to-opencv) disables CUDA which makes processing slow, and [downgrading OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567344/easyocr-segmentation-fault-core-dumped) is not possible due to incompatibility with my Python version and should not be required anyway as a fix should has been merged.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the order of import somehow works. CUDA can still be used.

```
import easyocr
import decord

ocr = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
```